# Recommendation about higher derivative theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, effective-field-theory

Are there some textbook or review about following parts of higher derivative Lagrangian?

1. How to figure out the degrees of freedom of higher derivative theory?
2. How to analyse the stability of a higher derivative theory? Are there ghosts in this theory?
3. How to do Hamiltonian analysis of higher derivative theory?
4. How to handle a theory with higher derivative and constraints or gauge freedom?
5. How to quantize such a theory? Are there some general procedures like canonical quantization?

I want to know whether this is thoroughly researched? If it is, then recommend some reviews and textbooks about this. I'm curious about this theory.

Comment: This comment is not QFT-related. In effective Lagrangian models, higher-order derivative may appear, see e.g. this review: http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0505583 , eq.(7) (the usual Ginzburg-Landau (GL) functional) vs. eq.(8) with 4-th order derivative (or 2-nd-order Laplacian). Such statistical functional appears due to the modulation of the order-parameter in the GL, such that the term $g\left|\nabla\Psi\right|^{2}$ in the GL has a negative $g$ and imposes to discuss a term $\gamma\left|\nabla^{2}\Psi\right|^{2}$ or more exotic ones.